# How can I extend the partition size without booting to the partition

Tags: windows-xp, partition

I'm looking for a way to extend a partition size from about 120g to 500g.  The partition is currently in sysprep mode - I'm not wanting to boot to the partition as it needs to stay in sysprep mode.  The computer currently has a windows XP NFTS partition on it.

Does anyone know any tools to use?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use diskpart.exe or another disk util in a booted OS "outside" the sysprep OS.

One way: Boot to the Windows Vista/7/2008 CD, once you get to a menu, hit F8 to pull up the command prompt, find which drive the HD is represented at (C: "maybe"), and use diskpart commands such as these to select and expand the drive.  http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/file-systems/how-can-i-use-diskpart-to-extend-a-volume-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a way. Boot the computer, wait till sysprep will finish, extend the partition and then reseal the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that sysprep mode doesn't lock or put funny flags on NTFS:

Grab a Linux CD like [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) and use `gparted` to resize partitions via a graphical interface.

Comment: Yes it was the sysprep part that I was unsure - not certain if resizing the partition will affect/destroy sysprep.